# Using @extend-Only to abstract Bootstrap selectors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have several styles that use Sass' @extend or @include to inherit properties from selectors imported from Bootstrap scss files.

I would like to convert all of the Bootstrap selectors to @extend-Only placeholders, so I do not have to include any original Bootstrap selectors in my final .css output. The goal is to write my own css classes, extend from Bootstrap only where desired.

For example, I wish to have a navbar called .super-freaky-nav:

```
.super-freaky-nav{
    @extend .navbar;
    @extend .navbar-default;
    @extend .navbar-top-fixed;
}
```

Ideally, my final .css output will not have a single reference to .navbar, .navbar-default, or .navbar-top-fixed.

Is there a way to do this without going into the _navbar.scss file and converting all of the selectors to @extend-Only classes (%navbar, %navbar-default, %navbar-top-fixed, etc)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Sass does not have the ability to do what you're asking for.  There's still a legitimate need to be able to extend normal classes and Sass has no way of differentiating between classes that should or shouldn't be extended.

Comment: I dug into this some more, you are correct as of the current version of Sass. There has been some discussion about adding a feature like this by the contributors, but it's been on the table for quite a while and hasn't been addressed. For now, I'm just creating my own extend-only placeholder versions of the Bootstrap selectors, which is really less than ideal for many reasons. Would love any other suggestions you may have. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any news on this? Would love to do the same. How about the following: include and compile everything in `application.css`, but don't reference this file from the website, but only another file which only holds the extended stuff (e.g. `only_my_selectors.css`)? So the client would only load the extended stuff.

Answer (score 2):

One potential implementation I'm exploring uses [custom importers in `ruby-sass`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#custom_importers) or [the experimental `importers` feature in `node-sass` (2.0+)](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental) to apply a `sed` (find and replace) transform to the Bootstrap Sass files, replacing leading class definitions with `%` syntax. I haven't gotten much past experimentation, though, and I don't know what I might break without a comprehensive visual test suite. Happy to have some help with it.

Comment: I've abandoned this effort in favor of [uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) and http://davidwalsh.name/uncss