# Best solution for mapping Bootstrap classes to other classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

`Edit:  This question has been marked as a duplicate and then linked to two other questions that do not answer my question.  My question is "what is the best approach" and the linked to questions are focused on the @extend sass method and absolutely no explanation of how this relates to my question.`

I have a Bootstrap web app that has some components where I can't change the HTML or CSS classes.

This makes things awkward to keep all the styles consistent and centralised so I can update an element style one place it updates everywhere.

I had the idea of trying to use the @extend SASS feature to pull in the bits I wanted from the Bootstrap SASS files.

So for instance if this is generated and I can't modify it:

```
<a href="#" class="myButton">Here is the button</a>
```

Then I could do something like this:

```
@import "bootstrap-sass-3.3.4/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap-sass-3.3.4/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/buttons";
@import "bootstrap-sass-3.3.4/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/vendor-prefixes";
@import "bootstrap-sass-3.3.4/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/tab-focus";
@import "bootstrap-sass-3.3.4/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/opacity";
@import "bootstrap-sass-3.3.4/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/buttons";


.myButton{
  @extend .btn, .btn-primary;
}
```

This generates just under 200 lines (before compression) of additional CSS for ".myButton" class.  While it works, I am not sure if this is the best approach as it will be adding a lot of size to my CSS files once I have several things mapped.  I guess this is not a big issue once its minified and compressed but it feels bad due to the redundancy.

I thought about using JavaScript to alter the HTML output but I am also not sure that is the right approach either due to javascript diabled browsers.

In my example I am just using my custom style sheet and then using a standard minified version of bootstrap.  To achieve what I want should I modify bootstrap core and use my compiled version?

This sounds like a fairly common issue so I assumed someone might have made a class mapper or something already but I couldn't find anything (apart from lots of geographical bootstrap maps).

What approach would you take?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280226/using-extend-only-to-abstract-bootstrap-selectors

Comment: @cimmanon I really can't understand what you've done here.  You closed question and linked me to 2 questions and I can't see how they answer my question. Neither of those questions pose any solution in a form I can relate to my question.  Could you furnish me with at least some small explanation so I can try to join the dots?

Comment: The answer is:  you can't.  Bootstrap is not written in a way that can be used the way you want with the constructs Sass offers.  You must modify Bootstrap if you want to be able to use it this way.

Comment: I can't what?  What is it that I cannot do?

Comment: I don't think you really read my question.  I suggested 3 approaches and asked which approach is best.  Your answer was to close the questions and say "you can't".  Your response is totally disjointed from my question and unhelpful.

Comment: Then your question is off-topic under the opinionated reason.  You seem to understand what your options are and the pros/cons of each one, so pick one.

Comment: Then why did you close it as a duplicate?  I've already shown how I am doing it, I don't think asking if there is a better approach is too broad in this scenario.  I think you are just being sloppy with your moderation.  I have seen multiple highly voted threads that pose multiple options and ask which is the best way.  I think that is on topic and what this site is for.  What do you get out of closing this question?

Comment: I'd say the answer depends on where you care for performance. Whether you care more for that server processing time (SASS), or the minified CSS resource for data transfer time, or client side work (JS).  If I were you I'd copy out the Bootstrap CSS parts I wanted into descriptive SASS objects I could extend for smaller reusable parts.  This gets you a smaller CSS file even if you see more in your SASS file.

Comment: On my website I've taken all my separate JavaScript resources and minified it into one file pre-empting a small and optimized file and it's boosted my sites load time.  I wouldn't modify boostrap core as that will prevent you from ever upgrading.  It gets messy.  Keep the changes you want separate and in small bits to use for yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  I was on the fence about modifying core, I just had that feeling that I was about to open a massive can of worms.  I've done what you said and I think it will be OK but I think I'll have a play with a few ideas.  For instance if I can identify the right `".btn{"` string in minified bootstrap I can replace it with `".btn,.myMappedClass{"` through a simple regex.  That is crude and nasty, I think there is probably a way to do this as a compilation task without modifying the core.  If only there was a website we could discuss such things...

Answer (score 0):

I can not think of other solution to your problem.. as you've sayed - it's either by using javascript to add .btn to every .myButton as needed or to use @extend.

you could go in middle and use javascript AND include `<noscript>` tag to import another css file with all the bootstrap @extend's as a workaround.

This way you deliver less code and you don't fill your css with lot of code lines and you can support browser with disabled js.